# explicit instantiation of function template fails (g++)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, g++, eclipse-cdt

I am experiencing some problems (i.e, linkage errors) with explicit instantiation of a function template. Under Visual Studio the project links ok, only under g++/Unix, using Eclipse-CDT, the linkage produce errors.

The function call is a part of a static library, which is linked with a dynamic library, in a big project.
The architecture of the function is as follows:

- function template declared (but not implemented) inside a namespace in my `MathUtils.h` file. One of the function arguments is itself a struct template, which is declared **and** implemented in this `h` file (under the same namespace).
- function implementation and instantiation is in `MathUtils.cpp`.
- function call is in `someFile.cpp` (which of course `#include "MathUtils.h"`) which is compiled & linked as a part of a static library.

The thing that drives me (almost) crazy, is that the build errors are not fully reproducible, and I suspect the Eclipse is to be blamed (maybe skipping some steps, although I use `clean project` before each build).

For about an hour, the Debug configuration built w/o errors but the Release failed with `undefined reference to...` linkage error. 
Then, for the next hour, both configurations failed. Then I made a small project, with only the 3 files mentioned above, and compiled it both from the command line and from Eclipse - no errors at all. Now Both configurations seem to link ok.

Did anyone experienced similar issues using the Eclipse-CDT? Any suggestions?

EDIT: since the problem is not easily (or at all) reproducible, I guess it will be hard to get an answer. I will update if I have any new insights.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. Solved it by moving instantiation *after* implementation in the `.cpp` with the class implementation.

myclass.hpp:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    // other declarations
};
```

myclass.cpp:

```
#include "myclass.hpp"

template <class T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass()
{
}

template class MyClass<int>;
template class MyClass<bool>;
```

Answer (score -1):

Quoting from [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)

*Because templates are compiled when required, this forces a restriction for multi-file

projects: the implementation (definition) of a template class or function must be in the same 
file as its declaration. That means that we cannot separate the interface in a separate header 
file, and that we must include both interface and implementation in any file that uses the templates.*

Comment: That is not true, look for `explicit instantiation`.

Comment: My mistake - I misread function templates for class templates.

Comment: Don't quote cplusplus.com. Seriously.