# Template instantiaton in multiple files

Tags: c++, file, templates, split, instantiation

I am currently implementing generic string related template class that does a lot of complex things. To optimize compile times I thought about implementing the functionality inside translation unit instead of header file and then instantiating types for UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32. The bottleneck that I'm trying to figure out is, if it's possible to split the template class instantiating into multiple translation units, since what one group of member functions does is very complex code and it would make a lot of sense to separate that into it's own translation unit.

Here's example what I'm trying to do:

example.h

```
template <typename T>
class Example
{
public:
  void test1();
  void test2();
};
```

example_test1.cpp

```
template <typename T>
void Example::test1()
{
  ...
}

template class Example<uint8_t>;
template class Example<uint16_t>;
template class Example<uint32_t>;
```

example_test2.cpp

```
template <typename T>
void Example::test2()
{
  ...
}

template class Example<uint8_t>;
template class Example<uint16_t>;
template class Example<uint32_t>;
```

Obvious (and hacky) solution would be to create mini "unity build" that includes example_test1.cpp and example_test2.cpp, but that's bit cheap way to do it and there would be only one translation unit. I wonder if there's any better solution?

EDIT: And please, if your answer is to "put it inside header", then don't. That's not helping. The idea here is to optimize compile time by removing stuff from headers that doesn't need to be there. Our compile time is already very high because of the excessive usage of templates in headers. And also I don't need tips about how to optimize compile times using other ways. I know how to use precompiled headers, etc. If I could just get answers that are on topic.

Comment: How exactly is splitting the member function definitions into separate files beneficial? And the terms you use don't make sense either. You talk about keeping them in separate *translation units* but then mention a possible solution as having some pre-build process including them all into a file. Well, now you've created a single *translation unit*! I suggest you stop over thinking it and just put all the definitions into the same file. You can go the explicit instantiation route if your template is only useful with those 3 types. Finally, consider using `char16_t` and `char32_t` for UTF-16/32

Comment: Praetorian: I am not overthinking it. The code is very complex and it makes it more readable to split it into two translation units. The solution that I suggested was hacky and yes, it would end up with one translation unit. That's why I'm looking for better solution. And I am unable to use any C++11 stuff since it's not adopted well by compilers yet, so I'm stuck with C++03 (this needs to work on other platforms than PC too). Also going to mention that in the real code we don't use uint8_t, etc. We got our own core library that provides good unicode support.

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree on the necessity of this. If readability/navigability is the issue, maybe you need a better editor. I don't think what you're asking for is possible. Anyway, strictly speaking, your solution isn't very portable either pre-C++11 because of the lack of extern templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called *explicit instantiation* and the correct syntax is following:

```
template class Example<uint8_t>;
template class Example<uint16_t>;
template class Example<uint32_t>;
```

If you really need to distinguish the methods into separate files, I would create a file `example_instances.cpp` for the code above, just to have it only once in the sources for better manageability. The code would be organized in the following way:

example.h

```
template <typename T>
class Example
{
public:
  void test1();
  void test2();
};
```

example_test1.cpp

```
#include "example.h"

template <typename T>
void Example::test1()
{
  ...
}

#include "example_instances.cpp"
```

example_test2.cpp

```
#include "example.h"

template <typename T>
void Example::test2()
{
  ...
}

#include "example_instances.cpp"
```

If you are discouraged from including `.cpp` files, put the instances into a separate header file. However, this one should be included *after* implementation unlike common header files ([explicit instantiation of function template fails (g++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368951/explicit-instantiation-of-function-template-fails-g)).

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to separate them is, that they need a lot of helper classes and functions that are specific to that function and no other could would ever benefit from them. That's why I wanted to separate those to own translation units and have internal linkage for the helpers for better encapsulation (and readability). so I would have something like, ClassName.h, ClassName.cpp, ClassName_ComplexMethod1.cpp, ClassName_ComplexMethod2.cpp. This is common programming practice that we've used.

Comment: @Venom OK, I’ve made an update. It should work but I haven’t tested this way.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to do compiller job. There is no instantation of member function of template classes if there is no call. So it is useless to define them in different translation units. Compiller do it without you and better than you. My advice is to put all your code into header file.

Comment: It is not useless. It saves a lot of compilation time and prevents using the class with types that it's not supposed to be used as side effect. If it was useless, it wouldn't be in the C++ standard.

Comment: Try to think about the third translation unit where you may want to use this code. What will you do? It is hard to maintain such code. Template export is in the standard but it is useless