# Explicit template instanciation but still undefined reference (with g++, but not with clang++)

Tags: c++11, templates, undefined-symbol

In the code below, I am getting

```
main.cpp: undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::_result<int, double>::type
                                  PPP<int>::operator()<double>(double const&) const'
```

even though that template is explicitly instanciated.  The code hase 3 modules: `man.cpp` uses `PPP<type>`, `ppp.cpp` explicit instanciates `PPP<int>` and `PPP<double>`, and `aaa.cpp` instanciates a method template.

Sorry for the lengthy test case, I couldn't get it shorter, and it appears the `result_type` template is needed for the fail.

### ppp.h

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

namespace
{
    template<typename T> struct _prio {};
    template<> struct _prio<int>    { using type = std::integral_constant<int,1>; };
    template<> struct _prio<double> { using type = std::integral_constant<int,2>; };

    template<typename A, typename X>
    struct _result
    {
        static constexpr bool cond = _prio<A>::type::value > _prio<X>::type::value;
        using type = typename std::conditional<cond, A, X>::type;
    };
} // ::anon

template<typename T>
struct PPP
{
    template<typename X>
    using result_type = typename _result<T,X>::type;

    T t;
    T operator () (const T&) const;

    // aaa.cpp contains an explicit instanciation for T=int, X=double
    // which is used in main().
    template<typename X>
    result_type<X> operator () (const X&) const;
};

// Instanciated in ppp.cpp
extern template struct PPP<int>;
extern template struct PPP<double>;
```

### ppp.cpp

```cpp
#include "ppp.h"

template<typename T>
T PPP<T>::operator () (const T& s) const
{
    return s + t;
}

template struct PPP<int>;
template struct PPP<double>;
```

### aaa.cpp

```cpp
#include "ppp.h"

template<class T>
template <class X>
auto PPP<T>::operator () (const X& x) const -> result_type<X>
{
    return x - (X) t;
}

extern template
auto PPP<int>::operator () (const double&) const -> result_type<double>;

template
auto PPP<int>::operator () (const double&) const -> result_type<double>;
```

### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "ppp.h"
#include <iostream>

extern template
auto PPP<int>::operator () (const double&) const -> result_type<double>;

int main (void)
{
    PPP<int> pi { 10 };
    std::cout << pi.t << std::endl;
    std::cout << pi (22) << std::endl;

    // Triggers with g++ v11.4, but not with clang++
    // main.cpp: undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::_result<int, double>::type
    //                                   PPP<int>::operator()<double>(double const&) const'
    std::cout << pi (33.3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### compile

```
$ <compiler> main.cpp ppp.cpp aaa.cpp -o main.x -Wall
```

Where `<compiler>` is one of `g++` or `clang++`.  With clang, it compiles and links fine, but with g++ v11.4 the linker complains

```
/usr/bin/ld: in function `main':
main.cpp: undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::_result<int, double>::type
                                  PPP<int>::operator()<double>(double const&) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I am adding `-save-temps -dumpbase ""` to g++ options, and then `cat aaa.s | c++filt`, the definition of the method can be seen, but it is neither `.global` nor `.weak`. And with `-O2` the method is no more present. With clang++ it is `.weak` and thus visible.

So can someone explain what I am missing?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4368951/1556746), but it seems not to provide a solution for the case above.

Comment: I wouldn't be using `anonymous` namespaces for the private template stuff, but a "private" namespace instead.  Whatever is built in aaa.cpp and ppp.cpp will not be in the same namespace as the `anonymous` one in the header.

Also I like to follow the rule of "If you're needing to explicitly instantiate template instances to make something build then you're probably doing something wrong"

Comment: For now I am using explicit instanciation because otherwise basically every bit has to be moved to headers, and the build times will sky rocket.  As I understand it shuld still work?

Comment: Also, if the anonymous namespaces are different, then clang++ is wrong when it links different namespaces?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts _"then clang++ is wrong when it links different namespaces?"_ - The anonymous namespace is a different TU-unique namespace in all translation units. `_result<int, double>` has 3 unique instantiations.

Comment: @Den-Jason: Thank you, with ordiary namespace it works.